# How to use filterLine() on Chunked Data via ServerSocket in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jetty, bufferedreader, serversocket

I'm trying to use a "ServerSocket" to receive HTTP messages from a client which is POSTing them as chunked.  I just want to capture the text content being posted (plain text).  Any input on how to do this better would be welcomed.

Here is my existing and very not-elegant solution.  When dealing with ServerSocket, one has to handle the headers and chunk barriers manually, and this is what I came up with.  I looked at filterLine() method on the reader, maybe that's part of a solution, i'm not sure. Don't know how to elegantly/reliably identify the chunked barriers.

```
socket.withStreams { input, output ->
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))

    while (currentLineCount < processor.newLineCount) {
        line = reader.readLine()

        if (line && line.size() > 3) {
            processor.processFormats(line)
        }
        currentLineCount++
    }
}
```

Caveats:

1. I have been trying to process line by line to minimize memory impact, rather than buffering the whole collection. I'd like to keep it that way.
2. These 4 Jetty libraries are available on the classpath, so I could leverage them, but can't add other libraries.

   compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.2.v20120308'
   compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.2.v20120308'
   compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.2.v20120308'
   compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.2.v20120308'

I would re-make the whole HTTP server and Handler in Jetty, but I've never used Jetty and can't find any good examples that fit my situation. Any suggestions with code samples for that would be great!

Comment: That version of Jetty is *very* old, and now EOL (End of Life).  Why not just use Jetty and/or Servlets to process the `doPost(request,response)` information?

Comment: They are on the classpaths of managed 3rd party systems which execute my embedded code.  They just happen to be the versions that are out there. This is not in my control.    Also, I just found that  servlet-api-3.0.0 and  netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar are on the classpath as well, so those could be used.